# Lógica para jogo da Cobrinha

Tags: c

Olá estou querendo fazer um jogo da cobrinha em C utilizando a biblioteca curses, comecei, porém não estou encontrando uma lógica para desenhar a snake na tela quando o usuario apertar as setas, quero saber como seria uma logica para desenha-la na tela de acordo com as teclas apertadas. Não sei se minha duvida ficou muito clara.

Answer (score 2):

Com uma busca breve, encontrei alguns tutoriais na net.

Breve explicação:

Você segura todas as unidades de cobra em uma lista.

Existe cabeça e cauda, que são os primeiros e os últimos elementos da lista. Por isso, é realmente uma fila.

A cada instante, determinar a direção em que você deve mover. Por exemplo, se a direção é à esquerda, depois coordenadas da proxima cabeça será em (-1,0) em relação a atual cabeça. Inserir nova unidade na lista na posição de cabeça com as coordenadas determinadas anteriomente.

Remova a unidade de cauda da lista (na tela).Que irá organizar o movimento. Se você encontrar uma comidinha na posição da cabeça, iniciar um contador de crescimento. A cada instante, de contra crescimento > 0, diminuí-lo e ignorar a remoção unidade de cauda. Assim, apenas a cabeça irá mover até que ele cresça.

> referencias:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471293/moving-snake-logic-in-processing
>
> https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33786/snake-game-logic
>
> http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2011/06/mini-projet-snake-game-in-c.html